# What's the point of Assignments?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I really don't see the point in completing the assignments anymore, since the amount of coins they award is less than they cost to create. And, supply officers are almost useless--yes, they may save time to create ONE item, but you need 40-90 items per assignment, so what's one more hour when you'll spend 89 hours anyway?!

I guess my question is, do the rewards for the assignments improve to make it worthwhile? So far they seem lame.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they're semi-random. Most of the time it's some coin amount far less than the investment cost. Other times they're Bux. I've typically seen 10 Bux at a time, by YMMV. I think that's all there is in the way of rewards.

Either way, the devs haven't updated the game since the beginning of April, so eventually the Assignments run out and then... nothing so far.

Answer (score 1):

The rewards will improve.

They improved for me after I added a few Imperial levels & got Vader making requests. About half of the time, he offers bux or VIPs as a reward.

I tend to ignore the requests that only offer coin rewards. If all 3 requests only offer coin rewards, I complete the cheapest one to make room for a Vader request.